# How to use UnsafeMutableRawPointer to fill an array?

Tags: swift, metal

I have a Metal texture, I want to access its data from Swift by making it a float4 array (so that I can access each pixel 4 color components).

I discovered this method of `MTLTexture` :

```
getBytes(UnsafeMutableRawPointer, bytesPerRow: Int, bytesPerImage: Int, from: MTLRegion, mipmapLevel: Int, slice: Int)
```

I don't know at all how to use UnsafeMutableRawPointer, how it works, and how to get the data back into a simple Swift array.

My first attempt was to create a pointer and allocate enough space like that, but I don't even know if that's what I should do:

```
var pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: myTextureSizeInBytes, alignedTo: 0)
```

Then I have no idea at all of how to get this data back into a standard Swift array...

Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, let's assume you have a `UnsafeRawPointer` and a length:

```
let ptr: UnsafeRawPointer = ...
let length: Int = ...
```

Now you want to convert that to an `[float4]`. First, you can convert your `UnsafeRawPointer` to a typed pointer by binding it to a type:

```
let float4Ptr = ptr.bindMemory(to: float4.self, capacity: length)
```

Now you can convert that to a typed buffer pointer:

```
let float4Buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: float4Ptr, count: length)
```

And since a buffer is a collection, you can initialize an array with it:

```
let output = Array(float4Buffer)
```

For much more on working with `UnsafeRawPointer`, see [SE-0138](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0138-unsaferawbufferpointer.md), [SE-0107](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md), and the [UnsafeRawPointer Migration Guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! Once I get the UInt8 array, how do I convert it to the desired type ? For instance if I want a float4 array what should I do ?

Comment: Sorry; I missed the request for a `[float4]`. I'll update.

Comment: Make sure to check Martin's answer; for your specific use case it is probably better.

Comment: Which (if any) steps cause a copy of the source data? The `Array` initializer?

Comment: Yes. Initializing an array from a collection copies the collection.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to create an array of the appropriate size
and pass the address to the underlying storage to the function:

```
var pixelData = Array(repeating: float4(), count: myTextureSizeInFloat4)
pixelData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
    texture.getBytes($0.baseAddress!, ...)
}
```

Inside the closure, `$0` is a `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer` 
representing the array storage as a collection of bytes, and
`$0.baseAddress` is a pointer to the first byte.

Comment: Agreed that for the use case described this is the better solution. I hadn't focused on how `getBytes` is called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why can we use `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer` while getBytes excepts an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: `$0.baseAddress!` is the `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`.

Comment: @MartinR Oh ok ! Thank you ! I'm trying that right now ! 

Comment: @MartinR I don't really get what is the difference between Buffer pointers and simple pointers... Do buffer pointers store anything ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: A buffer pointer describes the entire buffer, it is essentially a pointer to the first element and a length. It is also a collection, so you can for example iterate `for byte in myBufferPointer { ... }`.

Comment: @MartinR Ok ! Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like there is an issue, but I guess it comes from my texture.

Comment: Does the `texture.getBytes` line copy the data?

Answer (score 4):

### Details

- Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500), Swift 5.1

### Solution

```
extension UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    func toArray<T>(to type: T.Type, capacity count: Int) -> [T]{
        let pointer = bindMemory(to: type, capacity: count)
        return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: count))
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
let ponter = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: array)
print(ponter.toArray(to: Int.self, capacity: array.count))
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement @VasilyBodnarchuk's answer:

```
extension UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    func toArray<T>(to type: T.Type, capacity count: Int) -> [T] {
        return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bindMemory(to: type, capacity: count), count: count))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Swift 4 example of converting a literal UInt8 array to an UnsafeMutableRawPointer and back to an UInt32 array

```
static func unsafePointerTest() {
    //let a : [UInt8] = [0,0,0,4,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,12]
    let a : [UInt8] = [0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                       0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                       0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00] //little endian
    //0xFF, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0x12]  //317780223 = 12F0F0FF
    let b:UnsafeMutableRawPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating:a)
    let bTypedPtr = b.bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: a.count/4)
    let UInt32Buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bTypedPtr, count: a.count/4)
    let output = Array(UInt32Buffer)
    print(output)
}
```